# Modify Scheduled Task

Tags: windows, powershell, task, powershell-4.0

Hello I am trying to modify the action of one of our scheduled tasks in our task scheduler, but for some reason, it won't change a thing.

Here is my code:

```
function CreateOrUpdateTaskRunner(){
    $taskScheduler = New-Object -ComObject Schedule.Service
    $taskScheduler.Connect("localhost")

    $taskFolder = $taskScheduler.GetFolder('\')

    $task = $taskFolder.GetTask('Rebuild TotalSalesCache Next') 

    foreach($action in $task.Definition.Actions){
        $action.Path = "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\TotalSalesCache Builder\RunnerConsole2.exe"

        $taskFolder.RegisterTask([string]$task.Name, $task.Definition.XmlText, 4, "REMOVED", "REMOVED", 1, $null)
    }
}
```

When executing the code, no exceptions are thrown, but the task itself is not updated. Printing out the task after the `foreach` loop does not show an updated action either. Is there another way to change the action of the task?

Comment: Have you tested trying your function under a PS console where you're running as administrator? If you need to test, in a regular console, run `Start-Process powershell -Verb RunAs'

Comment: I am currently running it in the ISE, as administrator with no luck :(

Comment: Another way you could modify your task is through Set-ScheduledTask if you're on Windows 8/Server 2012 or newer.
MS link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/set-scheduledtask?view=win10-ps

Comment: Afraid my server is running 2008 R2 :-(

Comment: What about this approach for older OS's where it gets the content of the task as xml and replaces it?

https://superuser.com/questions/763639/modify-a-scheduled-task-with-powershell

Comment: I tried that, and ended up getting a corrupted task, which I had to delete from the file system, and re-create

Comment: Just to go back to basics for a moment, you are actually calling the function, correct?

Comment: @Nick Yes I am :-P I just left that part out of the code, as I didn't think it was relevant

Comment: What if you change your $ErrorActionPreference to "Stop"?

Comment: I would suggest running your code from a normal console not the ISE.

Comment: Again to go back to the beginning, what exactly is not updating. What are you expecting to see and what are you not seeing?

Comment: @Nick I am expecting to see that my scheduled task changes it's action. When we deploy our services, we mark them by date, so we can fall back to a previous version. This means that every time we deploy, the executable will have a unique name, which is why I have to update the action of the task.

Answer (score 0):

I never found a working solution on this issue, however I made a workaround.

Instead of changing the action of the scheduled task itself, I made a new powershell script, which runs my newly deployed application.
I made the task scheduler run my newly created script, and then changed the contents on this script, in my normal deploy script.